# Why does gtkmm automatically create a second thread sometimes?

Tags: linux, multithreading, gtk, gtkmm

If I compile and run the code as-is, the process will run with 1 thread.  If I uncomment the commented out section and then compile and run it, it runs with 2 threads.

I am compiling the code with this command: 
    g++ `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs` test.cpp

When the program is running I can check how many threads are created with:
    `ps -mC a.out`

If I look at the second thread in ddd, I can see that it is running `g_main_loop_run`.  This confuses me:

- What is the purpose of this thread?
- Why does adding a toolbar button create a new thread?
- I thought g_main_loop_run() should only ever run in one thread (unless you use the GDK_THREADS_ENTER/GDK_THREADS_LEAVE macros).  Since I am running Gtk::Main::Run() in my main thread am breaking the rules?

Thanks in advance for any help.  It's driving me crazy.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

bool OnDeleteEvent(GdkEventAny* PtrGdkEventAny)
{
    Gtk::Main::quit();
    return(true);
}

void OnExecuteButtonClicked()
{
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    new Gtk::Main(0, NULL);

    Gtk::Window *ptrWindow = new Gtk::Window;
    ptrWindow->signal_delete_event().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&OnDeleteEvent));

    /*
    Gtk::Toolbar *ptrToolBar = manage(new Gtk::Toolbar);
    Gtk::ToolButton *ptrToolButton;

    ptrToolButton = manage( new Gtk::ToolButton(Gtk::Stock::EXECUTE));
    ptrToolBar->append(*ptrToolButton, sigc::ptr_fun(&OnExecuteButtonClicked));

    ptrWindow->add(*ptrToolBar);
    */

    ptrWindow->show_all();
    Gtk::Main::run();

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: "I thought g_main_loop_run() should only ever run in one thread (unless you use the GDK_THREADS_ENTER/GDK_THREADS_LEAVE macros)" -- this sentence doesn't really make sense. Sure, the main loop and callbacks run in one single thread, but there's no guarantee that only one thread is used behind the scenes.

Comment: Okay, so I guess the answer is "don't worry about that other thread, it doesn't effect you".  I did a little experiment to make sure that callbacks were never invoked with the other thread's ThreadId and they weren't.  That was my main concern.  I guess Gtk probably uses the other thread to enhance performance.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `GThread`s are created when you use functions that rely on async behaviour. These usually create a `GTask` internally (with `g_task_run_in_thread` and friends) and run the synchronous version in a seperate thread (except for those being nativly async or async-able, those usually won't spawn another thread). Usually this is IO (i.e. GtkBuilder), Socket and IPC (dbus) related - so mostly `glib` stuff.

There might also be occasions which I am not aware of, that will spawn additional threads, the mainloop itself is strictly single threaded.

So in your case I can only think of two thing that could trigger this: The Stock image that is loaded from your local disk or the styling information of your theme.